# Where can i find the default WPF Control templates?

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate, gridviewcolumn

As per this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) link,

> There is no way to replace only part
>   of the visual tree of a control; to
>   change the visual tree of a control
>   you must set the Template property of
>   the control to its new and complete
>   ControlTemplate

.

I am trying to disable the click behaviour of GridViewColumnHeader ( I need to remove some triggers in the original control template), but i am not able to find the native "ColumnHeaderContainerStyle". All those i have found seem to have already done some customization and it is being difficult to get the original look and feel.

Can someone please suggest me how/where can i get the original control templates as defined in the native WPF controls?

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Use Reflector with Baml plugin to see xaml of default templates or maybe you can disable Grid behaviour in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How/Where to Find Microsoft Default Styles for WPF Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068830/how-where-to-find-microsoft-default-styles-for-wpf-controls)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control template for existing controls in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf)

Comment: Looks like ILSpy can do this as well now too; as well as Expression Blend and Visual Studio are able to extract many of the built-in ones as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can find the templates for all themes at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates).

Furthermore, there are several tools out there which can read the styles from an assembly.
For example, you could use [Style Snooper](http://wpfwonderland.wordpress.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/).
However, for your scenario (getting the built-in templates), the above documentation link should be the easiest.

Comment: Also Blend can extract the defaults.

Comment: Style Snooper link is no longer up to date.

Comment: All these links don't really work anymore, but you can find the templates on your development box, under the Visual Studio directory (for me, it's: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf\aero2.normalcolor.xaml`).

Answer (score 31):

In Visual Studio 2015 (at least) you can right click the control in the XAML designer and select "Edit Style->Edit a Copy" to view and edit the default template for a control. Much easier than cracking open Blend, downloading a style viewer, or searching the web.

Comment: This is da answer I was looking for. Place the control in visual xaml designer, right-click and go to "Edit Template-> Edit a copy..."

Comment: This does not work for me. Yes I get some "default", but it's not what I see on my Windows 10 machine !

Comment: BTW: When I do it in Blend, I get the correct default template !

Comment: When you "Edit a Copy," it creates a copy of the current style. I simply commented out that style to use the default template before I selected "Edit a Copy".

Answer (score 15):

I arrived at this question via Google a few times, and could not see the link I wanted, so here it is...

---

- [WPF styles and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates) (These are not actually the defaults.  I recommend avoiding these, and extracting them from Blend instead.)
- [Silverlight styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

These links have the following info for each framework control:

- Named template parts
- Visual states
- Full XAML default control template and resources

Comment: The WPF link is broken

Comment: These are just examples - they not reflect the default styles, they only cover most of it. you will notice the button has a blue'ish color which is not the default of a button in WPF.

Comment: If you're looking for WPF, try this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Corin, these are not standard values

Comment: Looks like the link is broken again (to clarify, the page loads, but selecting one of the controls to view the data takes you to a 404 page). -- @MikeNakis's answer below works.

Answer (score 4):

for vs2022 community : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\DesignTools\SystemThemes\

Answer (score 2):

As [this blog post](https://www.manuelmeyer.net/2014/08/wpf-the-simplest-way-to-get-the-default-template-of-a-control-as-xaml/) says, use this code (call it once) and read the output file (defaultTemplate.xml):

```
public static void SaveDefaultTemplate()
{
    var control = Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(ButtonSpinner));
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"defaultTemplate.xml"))
    {
        XamlWriter.Save(control, writer);
    }
}
```

In my opinion this is the best method.
Some elements like `DataGridCell` are not extractable through Visual Studio tweak: `Properties`>`Template`>`Convert to New Resource...` because you can't explicitly define any DataGridCell.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, this seems to be the link nowadays:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates

(I copied the template for button from that page, and it does indeed seem to be the one.)

Comment: Confirmed working as of the date of this comment.  Thank you for posting this. 