# How/Where to Find Microsoft Default Styles for WPF Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I am looking to change the style of a control but I basically want to copy part of a default style. Does anyone know how I can figure out what the default style of a control is?

In my case I am wanting to make the column headers in a DataGrid go blue on mouse over like the row headers do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control template for existing controls in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find some templates that are very close to the defaults on [this MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)

Another alternative is to get a copy of [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) and use it to make a copy of the default style, however Blend isn't free

Comment: The link you gave doesn't seem to actually have the default styles. It gives an example of how to set the styles (at least for DataGrid) but it isn't the default. I do have a copy of Blend, how would I use Blend to get a copy of the DataGrid template?

Comment: The link contains the default templates, however the colors shown for the DataGrid are customized and don't pull from the theme-specific colors like they usually do. You'd have to set them up yourself. If you're interested in only styling one part of the DataGrid I'd suggest  looking at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx), or you can use [this badly named page](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/wpf-kid-stuff-extracting) to see an example of using Blend to make a copy of the style.

Comment: any idea what the default colors are? Are those listed somewhere?

Comment: @KrisTrip They are different depending on what theme you are using, and the OS settings, but you can find the colors for the standard themes [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx). You can bind a color to a system brush by using the following syntax: `Foreground="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrush}"`

Comment: Today Blend is free inside Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to what Rachel says, the link she provides does *not* provide the default templates.

I have seen using `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(myObject.Template)` that the default templates are completely different from what that site shows.

Comment: You are correct, the first link I posted is not the exact defaults, although for most purposes I find they are fairly close. I've updated my answer to clarify that, thanks :)

Comment: After much searching, this is the only way that worked for ToggleButton. Even the XAML designer's `(right click component) > Edit Template > Edit a Copy` feature gives a bad template (the toggle button doesn't toggle). Thank you!