# Prevent WPF Textbox from changing appearance when focused

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

In my custom control I have 2 textboxes. When either one of them is focused, it changes its style slightly... it looses a bit of its border. I would like to prevent this behaviour, which seems to be default textbox behaviour.

Now, I assume that its something to do with the style, possibly with the part of the textbox template

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

However, is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel You have to edit `Focussed State StoryBoard`. For that edit your `TextBox Template` for changing the State.If you have `Expression Blend`  it will be easy for you.

Comment: I've not got expression blend, but looking at the default TextBox ControlTemplate I can't find the Focussed State Storyboard... i guess I'm really missing something crucial here? Is this storyboard in TextBoxBase? Or do I just set a new one? In any case, thanks for your answer so far

Comment: here's a question about where/how to find the default theme contents:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548319/where-can-i-find-the-default-wpf-control-templates

Comment: Ok, I see how it works, is there any easy way of removing a focussed state storyboard? Or do I overwrite it? So, I see the visual states for the TextBox control in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.100).aspx do I just define the Foccussed state again? (Sorry if this question may show a lack of WPF knowledge)

Comment: Ok, got it, if I just leave out the Focussed state storyboard in the TextBox style, then it will not change (which, in retrospect makes a lot of sense). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the default `TextBox ControlTemplate` which you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a control template for your custom control.
2. In the resources there, you need to style all text box target types. This way, you dont affect regular text boxes.

It would be helpful if you share some code which we can look at/modify to achieve what you need.