# How to get default template for WPF type that is not in XAML in VS2015?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to get default template for e.g. GridViewColumnHeader. However that is not in XAML and I cannot select mouse 2nd button and select Edit template. Is it possible to get with VS2015?

Comment: Check out Snoop, https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548319/where-can-i-find-the-default-wpf-control-templates) question the same?

Comment: it indeed is, but the answers make no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open Blend for Visual Studio, add a temporary `<GridViewColumnHeader />` element to an open document, right-click on it in the "Objects and Timeline" view and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy. This will copy the default template into your XAML markup.

[image]

Comment: thanks! i'm an idiot. i've been doing this before. i tried to add it from Toolbox but it didn't have it. One has to write it in XAML.