# WPF Generate Xaml template

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

How do i get the default xaml template for a control?
In expression blend you can right click a control and press style then i generates the current template as xaml.. how do i do this if i don't have expression blend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XAMLPad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398%28VS.90%29.aspx#xamlpad_features) or [`StyleSnooper`](http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/05/Revamped-Style-Snooper.aspx) or [`Reflector`](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: i have reflector but how do i go from the class to get xaml?

Answer (score 1):

just verify this link

[Control template for existing controls in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf)

You can use Reflector tool to get resource like xaml of existing controls

Answer (score 1):

.

For WPF,

[Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)

For Silverlight,

[Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075%28VS.95%29.aspx)

.

Answer (score -1):

HI
No way just Use **Microsoft expression blend**. use trial-ver :)