# Where to find XAML markup for default WPF controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Control template for existing controls in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf)

The deeper into WPF development I get the more I feel the need to customize controls to suit my needs. The problem is that I don't know where to find the baseline XAML to begin changing styles. Searching for example on Google "wpf style calendar" yields plenty of results where people have made a lot of modifications with what appears to be XAML used from the default style. I can't imagine it was all hand written.

I tried using Snoop but that only appears to tell me the hierarchy and not the XAML used.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1559261/314334

Answer (score 3):

You might try [Style Snooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/). It shows not exact XAML, but that's better than nothing.

Comment: I would not bother with external tools when the templates are available [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (`WPF Default Themes` link)...

Comment: @H.B. may be you should post your comment as the answer?

Comment: Well, i would, if this question wasn't a duplicate