# How can I get the default XAML style for the WPF DatePicker control in .net 4?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to find the default control template for the WPF DatePicker control in .NET 4.  I have tried the MSDN page, but the "link" to the DatePicker control is just text.  I have tried StyleSnooper, but it has an error when loading PresentationFramework.dll.

Is there any way other than Expression Blend to get the default template?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control template for existing controls in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf)

Comment: It is not a duplicate.  If you look at the link given in the other question, the "DatePicker" control does not have a valid link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx

Comment: As i noted in the comments of the accepted answer on that question people are looking for the `Default WPF Themes`, people should actually read the pages they are linked to and not just look for shiny links...

Comment: Also if you check the lefthand side there even is a page for the DatePicker, but the templates on those pages are only examples anyway, so **they are not what you have been looking for in the first place**.

Comment: I have now moved my comment into the actual answer so its more visible by the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download them from this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx), or more specifically [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812).

Comment: We really should close this though, just had a question like this yesterday (also a duplicate of course)..

Comment: @H.B. Agreed, will leave answer up for now though :)

Comment: Thank you.  The second link appears to have styles for the DatePicker.  The first one does not.

Comment: +1 for link to excellent and useful resource... (the 'here' one).

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can also used Blend to extract a style for any control.