# Styling Separator in WPF to match background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a background with a custom color for a ContextMenu.  I added in a separator as so (between different menu items):

```
<Separator Background="#EDECEC" Margin="0" ></Separator>
```

The background color is #edecec.  However, I see a separator, and the color doesn't match the rest of the contextmenu.  It is lighter than the contextmenu.  Is there a way to change that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Separator` in menus has a [default `Template`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf) which ignores the `Background`, to override it add a respective style to some ancestor's `Resources` using the right key:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <!-- ControlTemplate with a TemplateBinding to Background here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Could I achieve the same effect by just drawing a line instead?

Comment: Visually probably yes, but you'd need to make sure the containing MenuItem is disabled, you normally don't want a clickable separator. That being the case actually using a separator might be best as it is meant for this and integrated into the framework.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what that TemplateBinding would look like? Dumb question, I know, but I'm running my head into a wall (Unfamiliar with XAML)

Comment: @LeesusFreak: Should be something like `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`, or if the template uses a shape it'll probably be a `Fill` that is bound to `Background`.