# Set the MenuItem BackGround color (The right way)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Whenever I try to change the background color to a menu adding the following code to the app.xml

```
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9B9B9B" />
    </Style>
```

I get this lighter shade of gray around the menu, which color isn't set by the background property:

[image]

I know there are similar questions around, but the answers I've found haven't helped me.

Comment: I don't see your point. Is the background not set or what?

Comment: It has this border in a lighter shade of gray. Same with the separator. Everything should be in the same color but I can't find a way to set up the color of that border thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of thing is coded into the various ControlTemplates for MenuItems. You will probably have to create your own. (You could copy [the defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf) and edit them to your liking though)

Comment: The link led me to create a style which is applied to the menuItem. I edited the style and changed the background and got the same result, since it's the same background property. The menuItem still has a border in another color which I can't seem to get ahold of.

Comment: Somewhere buried in those +300 lines of code there's another parameter `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SubMenuBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF9B9B9B"/>` which changes the color. Thanks!

Comment: @hikizume: As i said, there are various ControlTemplates, each one for a different role of the MenuItem, somewhere there should one which references this resource in its template (it has the component-id `SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey`).