# How can I completely customize popup from MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have normal menu in XAML. And I would like to completely change looks of the popup that gets displayed when you click on menu item.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="MyCustomMenu">
        <MenuItem.PopupTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="SexyImage"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </MenuItem.PopupTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Popup is your custom control? I can't get the question. Or you mean ContextMenu control as popup?

Comment: It's an example. By popup i mean the context menu that literaly pops up when you click on menu. However I don't want it to be ContextMenu I want to be able to put anything on there. Let's say an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the template of the `MenuItem` since the Popup is a part of it, have a look at the [default templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf) to get an idea of what a template should look like. [`MenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.aspx) has a [`TemplatePartAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx) for said popup.

Answer (score 1):

Define following styles in resources of your application:

An example of style overriding for MenuItem:

```xml
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                       .... here is your custom template
```

ContextMenu styles overriding:

```
<Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
```

Comment: Ok, this is a good way to customize ContextMenu and items within it. Thanks for code. It is helpful. But this is not exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @Kugel : have you found a solution for your task?

Comment: I think H.B. suggenstion will work. I'm giving it a try. I'll post results later.

Comment: @Kugel : I believe my example also overriding MenuItem template by specifying setter for property Template and providing ControlTemplate for menuItem type, am I right?