# How to make a keyboard scrollable readonly WPF TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

It seems such a simple thing to do: use a TextBox to display some output and allow the user to cut and paste from it, scroll it but not edit it.

BUT: if a TextBox is readonly, then it loses most of its keyboard behaviour. You can click on it and select text using the invisible cursor, but it will not scroll or navigate.

I have this (terrible) solution.

```
<TextBox Focusable="True"
     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
     FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="10pt"
     Foreground="{Binding Path=OutputTextColour}" 
     Text="{Binding Path=OutputText}"
     Background="White" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

And a handler to throw away any attempts to edit:

```
   private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  // the IsReadOnly flag on the control doesn't let the navigation keys work! WPF BUG?
  if (!(e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right 
     || e.Key == Key.Home || e.Key == Key.End || e.Key == Key.PageDown || e.Key == Key.PageUp 
     || e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Escape))
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I have also tried a readonly TextBox inside a ScrollViewer, but it seems the TextBox, even when readonly, still swallows the navigation keystrokes and the ScrollView never sees them. If the ScrollViewer gets the focus then scrolling works and cut/copy/paste do not!

Yes, I could probably get all that to work by some fancy footwork with PreviewKeyDown, but really I just want a TextBox that plays nice!

Comment: For your current solution, what about when I want to hold down shift and select with the arrow keys, or Ctrl to select whole words?

Comment: What keyboard behavior is missing?  I can shift and ctrl-select text...I can use arrow keys and scroll with mouse selection

Comment: @Bubba: PgUp, PgDn, Home, End, Ctrl+Home, Ctrl+End lose their scrolling behaviour.

Comment: @Mathemats: they work OK. Arrow keys are not marked as handled, so get passed through.

Comment: I might be missing something, but your if statement reads if the key pressed is _not_ (left, up, etc) then handle it. Wouldn't you want to handle these key presses? Also, throw some braces around the body of the if...

Comment: @Mathemats: if the key is not left, up etc then mark it handled so it doesn't get passed through. Only allow TextBox to see these chars. [And I NEVER write unnecessary braces -- you shouldn't either.]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is to set

```
IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"
```

as described here:

[Readonly textbox for WPF with visible cursor (.NET 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580285/readonly-textbox-for-wpf-with-visible-cursor-net-3-5?rq=1)

Works beautifully!

Comment: thanks! That sounds like the answer. I can't check it out right now, but hopefully real soon now...

Comment: This worked for me - looks like the correct answer @david.pfx

Comment: This made the Page Up and Page Down button page the document but not the Cursor keys.  Still an easy improvement over what I had before.