# Menu margin color

Tags: wpf, menu, colors, margin

I am getting the following "margin" around my menuitems that i cannot figure out how to remove:

[image: screenshot]

I have tried setting the margin to 0 and adjusting the border brush color, nothing seems to work.

I am just looking to either change the color to match the background or remove it completely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the `Template` of the `MenuItem` as that part might not be configurable via properties. ([-How to get the default template-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf), so you can modify it)