# Adding a progress bar to the background of a WPF control

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, progress-bar

How can I modify certain WPF controls (i.e. combobox, textbox, etc) to have a progressbar in the background of the control (which I can enable and disable on demand). I don't need it to actually show an accurate progress, rather I just need an indication that this control is waiting for something to finish. A spinning icon inside the control would be OK too.

I have seem some answers that deal with having one control on top of another and setting transparency, etc, but I would greatly prefer to find a better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put anything anywhere, you just need to modify the respective [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx), which may not be trivial, you could start by copying [the existing ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf).

To enable and disable easily you maybe should subclass the control you target so you can have a dedicated dependency property for that which can be bound to the `Visibility` of the `ProgressBar` in the template (perhaps with a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`).

Comment: I concur with this answer.  You can do a lot of custom stuff in WPF , so this could also be achieved with a user Control (or Custom Control, if needed).  However, providing a new control template and a sub-classed control would also be my recommendation.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. In order to modify the control template, do I need to know what the existing one is? For example, I am using DevExpress's ComboBoxEdit, which might have a different Template than what you linked to.

Comment: @user981225: You do not need to know the details, but you need to know the essential parts, usually those are noted as [attributes on the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx). These controls need to appear in the template and should have the respective part-name.