# Editing Button Design

Tags: wpf

I customized the design of a button in WPF but when I hover over the button it shows the default design of the button.

This also happens to combo boxes.

Comment: Did you also customize the design of the various visual states? Please share your Style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like you just changed things by setting various appearance related properties, but to fully customize the button you need to change the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx). See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) for an example style (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf) if you need to get the default tenmplate of it)