# How to hide combobox toggle button if there is only one item?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, visibility, togglebutton

I have a WPF application. In one window there is a combobox..and I want to hide the toggle button and disable the combo box if there is only one item.

How would I achieve this ?

I have tried the below code for hiding the toggle button. But of no luck

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=C}"  >                    
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, ElementName=CList}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The better solution is to replace the template of combo box with a control template(which only contain textblock) when the item count is zero.

Here is the xaml for the same.

```
<ComboBox Name="CList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=C}" 
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CC}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                    <ComboBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" >
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, ElementName=CList}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0], ElementName=CList}" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.Style>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: I used this solution too, it worked fine, so thank you. I know this is an old post, but is there a way to update the value in the text box when the one item in the list changes?

Comment: This doesn't work if you've already created a template for your combo box.

Comment: @RandallDeetz and everyone that already set a template, you can add `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"` to the style (behind TargetType). That fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

You would need to change the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) of the `ComboBox` and implement the trigger inside that. You have no access to the controls in the template from the outside.

*(You could copy and modify the [existing template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf), directly modifying a part of the template is practically impossible)*

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a Converter also:
(Sorry I didn't fully read your question)

### Converters

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WPFSandbox
{
    public class ComboBoxItemCountToEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(Int32))
            {
                if ((int)value > 1)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class ComboBoxItemCountToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(Int32))
            {
                if ((int)value > 1)
                    return Visibility.Visible;
            }

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<Window 
... 
...
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WPFSandbox">

<Window.Resources>
    <converters:ComboBoxItemCountToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ComboBoxItemCountToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <converters:ComboBoxItemCountToEnabledConverter x:Key="ComboBoxItemCountToEnabledConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding C}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=C.Count, Converter={StaticResource ComboBoxItemCountToEnabledConverter}}"/>
   <ToggleButton Visibility="{Binding Path=C.Count, Converter={StaticResource ComboBoxItemCountToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I want to hide toggle button, not combo box completely.