# How to make text wrap in a WPF TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, word-wrap, treeviewitem

This time, my question is as simple as it sounds... how do you get text to wrap in a WPF `TreeViewItem`?

I have a simple `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with just one `TextBlock` in it.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

The text does not wrap.

I tried binding the `Width` of the `TextBlock` to the `ActualWidth` of the `TreeView`, but although that makes the text wrap, the `Width` of the `TreeViewItem` does not fit in the `TreeView` because the `TreeView` has `Padding`. Binding to the `ActualWidth` of the `TreeViewItem` has (unsurprisingly) the same effect. Another downside to this is that even the items with little text stretch outside the `TreeView` bounds.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, 
ElementName=TreeView}" />
```

Surely there must be a better way, like somehow informing the `TreeViewItem` of the `TreeView`'s bounds... I can't believe it doesn't know automatically. But how can I do this?

**UPDATE >>>**

Thanks to H.B.'s answer, I managed to change the `Grid.ColumnSpan` to 2 on the `Bd` `Border` he mentioned in the `ControlTemplate` and it set the width so that the text now wraps nicely. The problem is that I am using this `ControlTemplate` for other `TreeViewItem`s in other `TreeView`s where I don't want full width items.

The solution I came up with is simple. I have bound the `TreeViewItem.Tag` value to the `Grid.ColumnSpan` property in the `ControlTemplate` like so:

```
<Border Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
Name="Bd" Grid.Column="1" ... />
```

This allows me to change the `Grid.ColumnSpan` and therefore the full width or ordinary width behaviour of the `TreeViewItem` by setting the `TreeViewItem.Tag` value to either 2 or 1 respectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at [the default template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf) of `TreeViewItems` you will see a Grid like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                          Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- ... -->
```

As you can see the third column takes all available space while the others are on `Auto`, the header is placed in the second column inside a border:

```xml
<Border Name="Bd"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ...
```

This means that the column will become as large as the header, there is no restriction on it. Thus the header just gets bigger than the `TreeView` itself.

If you add `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` to this Border it will occupy the third column as well, which is restricted by how much space is left, hence the text will wrap; this will however extend the header across the whole width which might look a bit odd when selecting it.

Of course you will also need to disable horizontal scrolling:

```xml
<TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...
```

[image: A screenshot]

Comment: I was hoping for a simple property, but that did the trick, thanks so much. +1

Comment: @Sheridan: Glad that helped :) It always sucks if certain things are hardcoded in the default templates...