# How to add a TreeViewItem in the middle of two HierarchicalDataTemplates?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a Tree View that looks like this:

[image]

The data from this tree view is coming from a ViewModel with nested objects. The classes of this objects looks like this. I changed some of the code for privacy purposes:

```
public class RegistroModel {
    public ObservableCollection < ClassA > ClassA { get; set; };
}

public class ClassA {
    public ObservableCollection < ClassB > ClassB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB {
    public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
}
```

The xaml of this TreeView looks like this:

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Registros}" TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeView_Selected" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RegistroModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassA}">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:ClassA}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassB}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:ClassB}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClassC.Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Now, what I want to do, is to wrap some HierarchichalDataTemplates within a expandable Label to look like this:

[image]

I want to wrap the HierarchicalDataTemplate of `RegistroModel` with the label INGRESOS, the one corresponding to the `ClassA` model with CAUSAS PENALES label and the one with `ClassB` with DELITOS label. I don't know if I have to use Labels o TreeViewItems to wrap the HierarchicalDataTemplate.

Is there a way to do this without changing the ViewModel structure and only changing the XAML? What is the best and easiest way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934934/how-to-make-text-wrap-in-a-wpf-treeviewitem

Comment: @trix that question is not related with what I am asking