# How to make checkbox bigger

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm using a checkbox control like this:

```
<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" 
      Grid.Column="0" 
      FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
      Content="{Binding Name}">
</CheckBox>
```

The thing is that I change size to be a little bigger. In this case text is getting bigger, but tick itself remains the same. It looks ugly, can I resize checkbox somehow?

**UPDATE**
I'm doing it on *windows phone* so LayoutTransform not appropriate here

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087063/changing-the-size-of-a-checkbox-and-the-check-mark-in-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up with the following:

1. Add an empty checkbox
2. Open control in expression blend
3. Select checkbox there
4. Open Edit Template -> Edit Copy
5. It will create a new style with custom template that you will be able to assign to checkboxes.

It produced about 150 loc style, but I couldn't find another way

Comment: This is the real way to do it. Good explaination :)

For lazy people, Shrikant S added the code as an other answer...

Answer (score 125):

Try some thing like this:-

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
    </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
</CheckBox>
```

You can also check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/98cf8a65-f4ca-4ff5-9851-c2989b91a013)

Comment: LayoutTransform is not accessible in windows phone

Comment: In my experience , the [StackPanel approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484367/350933) from @bmeredith plays much nicer with positioning.  The ScaleTransform approach requires margin offsetting to get the output lined up with other controls.

Answer (score 12):

```
    <StackPanel Height="80"
                Name="StackPanel1"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Viewbox Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=StackPanel1}">
            <CheckBox />
        </Viewbox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Adjust the StackPanel height as needed.

Comment: No offense, but googled and searched for viewbox. Seems right for the question, but I cannot add it on a xaml page. WHY? Am I missing a library. I checked in add Items on toolbar, it was there, but still cannot add it to the page.

Comment: Good question. Although I don't write code for WP7, I was under the assumption Viewbox was made part of WP7 at some point. Maybe check out this link for some ideas. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/working-with-viewbox-control-in-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 3):

```
                ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(2.0, 2.0);
                yourCheckBox.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                yourCheckBox.RenderTransform = scale;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add below mention codes in windows/usercontrol resource, it will automatically increase the default size of the []checkbox inside a Xaml control.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z "
                                      Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}" Margin="5" Opacity="0" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Program Code. Is. Uncountable.  https://blog.michael.gr/2023/05/code-is-uncountable.html

Answer (score 2):

[image: LargeCheckBox]

**WPF Modified example**

- **markGrid**   Width="24", Height="24"
- **optionMark**   Margin="4", Stretch="Uniform"
- **indeterminateMark**   Margin="4"

  ```
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxLarge" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid" Width="24" Height="24">
                                <!--  Width,Height,Stretch="Uniform",Margin  -->
                                <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="4" Opacity="0" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="4" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
  ```