# XAML: How can I bind a DependencyProperty to a C# property of the same name on a different object?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Using:

- Visual Studio Community Edition 2015
- .Net 4.0

I've implemented [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093312/639739), producing my own `CheckBox` class complete with an `IsChecked` `DependencyProperty`. That property is backed by the `IsChecked` property on the WPF `CheckBox`, or would be if it would work. Working would mean my getter and setter are called when the checkbox is toggled.

If I rename my property to `IsChecked_temp` and modify the XAML to match, it works fine. I think this is a naming conflict, but why doesn't `ElementName` resolve it? My minimal test case follows.

EDIT 0: I forgot to mention, I get no errors or warnings.

EDIT 1: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425144/639739) was initially accepted because it works for the test case, but it's apparently not the entire answer. Applying it to my project (and renaming the `CheckBox` class to `ToggleBox`) yields a `XamlParseException` at every use of the property:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'IsChecked' property of type 'ToggleBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

I'll try to get a minimal test case going to show this.

**CheckBox.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CheckBox_test.CheckBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="Self">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Self}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**CheckBox.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CheckBox_test
{
    public partial class CheckBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
             "IsChecked",
             typeof(bool),
             typeof(CheckBox),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                     FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        public CheckBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="CheckBox_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckBox_test">
    <Grid>
        <local:CheckBox />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (for completeness)

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CheckBox_test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for test, try to write IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=Self}"

Comment: @Spawn I tried that with and without `_temp` and got the same respective results. Worth a try, though, so thanks.

Comment: Ok, i'll try tomorrow... Self is not so rare name for UserControl, so it must work. Can you tell, what Visual Studio and .NET version you use?

Comment: I've edited those details into the question.

Comment: Oh, and I get the same (lack of) behavior on .Net 4.5.2.

Comment: I fail to understand what's the use of this. If you want a CheckBox use a CheckBox, not an UserControl....... You should avoid trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: He's just wrapping the checkbox (or any control) in more complex control which is simplified for illustration :)

Comment: @kirotab sounds pretty bad IMO. People conflate the usages of `UserControl` and *custom control*, which are 2 completely different concepts, intended for different use cases.

Comment: @HighCore I've got to confess that I'm one of those people that you speak about. So thank you for reminding me that there is such a thing as `CustomControl`. Definitely something that I needed to do earlier but tomorrow will try to expand my knowledge in the area a bit.

Comment: Ditto. I remember encountering `CutomControl` a long time ago and not understanding why it exists. However, that's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question (at least for me) so it turns out that there is really a conflict of names when you register your Dependency Property.

I'm not exactly sure if this is an answer but I think you'll find this interesting if you didn't knew or thought about it before.

I've used "CheckBox.IsChecked", but any unique name would suffice probably.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
         "CheckBox.IsChecked",
         typeof(bool),
         typeof(CheckBox),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                 FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

This works without change in the name of your property

```
public bool IsChecked
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
    }
}
```

> When you create names for your dependency properties, you must choose
>   unique names that are not being used for dependency properties or
>   events in any base classes that you inherit from; otherwise, an
>   ArgumentException is thrown during runtime. For more information about
>   dependency properties and activity binding, see Custom Activity
>   Binding Sample and Simple Activity Sample.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734499(v=vs.90).aspx

Yet another reminder how big of a noob I am :)

Comment: This solves my problem, even though I don't seem to satisfy the criteria that the conflicting name is "used for dependency properties or events in any base classes that you inherit from." Kudos for this find.

Comment: Yep, it was just not working with all the binding types that I've tried without changing the name or making the property a normal one instead of dependency... The material is from .net 3.5 and doesn't have newer version (at least I didn't found one) so maybe there are changes...

Comment: No man, I thank you, because I've had terrible issues with some dependency properties that I labeled as "Dark Magic" at the time (seemed so illogical how they behave), so now at least I have one more weapon to try to fight them.

Comment: Odd. When I implemented this in my actual project, it didn't take. Looks like I need to build a new question about why this doesn't always work.

Comment: Hm, if you change the class name to something 100% unique like "asd" instead of "CheckBox.", if it still doesn't work just unmark the answer and maybe somebody smarter than us will explain.