# Combobox custom dropdown button

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am making a WPF combobox but the dropdown button is way too small and I need to make it bigger. I tried searching through the properties in the user control but I couldn't find anything. If someone could help me, that'd be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you are using WPF, all you have to do is redefine the control template. that is one of the great things about WPF. the controls are "lookless" and you can tell define what they look like or you can use the default. [here is the default template.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) and [here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx) on using control templates to customize your WPF

Comment: That is not the default template, it's an example template. How to get the defaults: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf