# Deriving (Expanding) a Control Template in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, datagrid

I have this DataGrid I want to change the Disabled behaviour (xaml);
I want to change this small part in the template.

If it is not possible i dont mind to use:

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
```

And To replace the entire xaml (template) of my control, But I need the complete template to copy paste and help where to change the Disabled look-like part.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please explain what is it that you exactly want to achieve? You want to apply a new template to WPF DataGrid and you want the current control template of `DataGrid` to override on top of it?

Comment: to use the same template , only to change the IsEnabled foreground from gray to green (override this part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: It's been pointed out that all the default control templates are available at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) which makes the below relevant, but I'll leave it here for interest.

Given an instance of a control you get serialize the markup for the control template using the `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter` class.

To get a control template:

`string markup =  System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(control.Template);`

To get a complete dump (including triggers etc) of the control template use.

```
        StringBuilder markupBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(markupBuilder);

        System.Windows.Markup.XamlDesignerSerializationManager manager = 
            new System.Windows.Markup.XamlDesignerSerializationManager(writer);

        manager.XamlWriterMode = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriterMode.Value;

        // data grid named dataGrid1
        var template = dataGrid1.Template;

        System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(dataGrid1.Template, manager);

        string markup = markupBuilder.ToString();
```

If you just looking to change the foreground color of the DataGrid when it's disabled, you should be able to use styles together with triggers rather than replacing the entire template.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                    Value="False">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                    Value="False">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <!-- Column Definitions -->
</DataGrid>
```

Adding the above 2 styles to the DataGrid's resources collection will, set the foreground of each column header and data row cell to green when the DataGrid is disabled.

Comment: That kind of work is unnecessary, you can get all the templates on MSDN, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf

Comment: @H.B. Oh... I didn't know. Definitely easier :)

Comment: Also, Expression Blend allows you to create copies of the templates of any control...

Comment: Thanks. I tried:   <Setter Property="Template"> <Setter.Value>  than pasting your xaml above but it destroys my grid, meaning it does not function as before - no rows are visible etc.

Comment: Place the DataGrid.Resources element directly within the DataGrid element.

Comment: I did not put it into the dataGrid, I added the two styles sepratley in my ResourceDictionary (under DataGrid.Resource it throws an exception). ThankS!

Answer (score 0):

To define the disabled behavior of any control, you should change the Disabled visual state accordingly in the control template.

Comment: i dont see it...is the one posted here correct? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/8e6f3c70-f65f-4152-9469-9ae3e9239126 if so where is the part you said?