# Remove the Thumb from Scrollbar

Tags: wpf, slider, scrollbar

[image]
I want to remove the Thumb from the scrollbar when the IsEnabled property of the Scrollbar is Set to false. How can it be done in the code behind ? Please help.

Comment: are you talking about the Cursor???

Comment: @ gaurawerma : i have uploaded an image to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make custom control template (based on standard template - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173(v=vs.85).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173.aspx) for you scrollbar without thumb.

Comment: Those are *not* the default templates, it even says `Example` in the title, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf).

Comment: Yes, my bad, didn't notice that. I hoped that MS finally managed to publish control templates in all themes to help people to avoid to manually restore them with XamlWriter or Blend or other apps

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way: Set Maximum equal to Minimum, and the thumb will disappear altogether. :-)

Comment: Does this work for you? https://github.com/logiclrd/TestScrollBarHideThumb

Comment: I ended up looking for the thumb using the VisualTreeHelper and hiding it.