# C#, TabControl, Visual Styles - How can I give a panel a visual background similar to the TabControl background?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, gradient, visual-styles

How could I give a panel or any other control the style of a TabControl (the control itself, not the tab pages). What I mean is to give a control a border, then a shadow effect, and a gradient background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at control template for TabControl (how to get default control templates - [Control template for existing controls in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf)) and create appropriate styles/control templates for your controls.

Comment: I don't know much about WPF, would I have to learn that to do this? I do want to learn WPF but would rather have a quicker alternative at the moment.