# how to change icon expander in wpf

Tags: wpf

Is there a way I can change the icon of the expander to +/- with the color white as the foreground color? I've been looking everywhere but cant find a simple solution. Or better yet, how do I change the color of the expander icon to white? My background is a dark color, so this is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to create a custom control template, see this CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248112/Templating-WPF-Expander-Control

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx), you can base it on the [existing template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf) though.

Comment: so even if i just wanted to change the foreground of the icon to white, i would still have to change the whole template? isnt there an easier way of doing to without having to change the template?

Comment: There is no easier way, the icon is part of the template and it is not bound to any properties you can change, hence you need to replace the whole template. (Unless you want to modify the controls at runtime which is a ***very*** bad idea as the themes are OS dependent)