# How to make TreeViewItem non collapsible

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem

I am working on a WPF project and I have a `TreeView` using `HierarchicalDataTemplates`. I have been able to establish some different levels of nodes. Everything is going well so far.

```
<TreeView Margin="14,14,14,14" Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}"
                               BorderThickness="0">
                  <TreeView.Resources>
                    <!--
                        First Level
                    -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstLevelViewModel}" 
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkBlue"  />
                        </StackPanel>                           
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <!--
                        Second Level
                    -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SecondLevelViewModel}" 
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                            <CheckBox Name="checkBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" FontSize="14" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
. . . .
```

My problem is that: **I need some nodes to be non collapsible.**

**Is there any way to achieve that? I have been searching about it with no luck.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559261/control-template-for-existing-controls-in-wpf) of the `TreeViewItem` defines a `ToggleButton` which shows and hides the sub-items. You can create your own template based on that in which the `IsEnabled` property is bound to some property on your item, so that it can be prevented from being toggled, of course you should also bind the `IsExpanded` (can be done outside the template as well) and the value in that case should always be `true`.